# How to mark a position while reading a file in java?

Tags: java, reset

I wrote a parser in java that parses several features from a text file.The idea is to get a block of lines corresponding to the corresponding headline.

For instance, if I have this:

```
CC   -!- FUNCTION: Adapter protein implicated in the regulation of a large
CC       spectrum of both general and specialized signaling pathways. Binds ...
```

I'll need to get this:

```
Function :  Adapter protein implicated in the regulation of a large spectrum of both general and specialized signaling pathways. Binds ....
```

I can do that without any problem for all the features from that type of text file.

The problem comes when I have this:

```
CC   -!- FUNCTION: Adapter protein implicated in the regulation of a large
CC       spectrum of both general and specialized signaling pathway ...
CC   -!- SUBUNIT: Homodimer. Interacts with SAMSN1 and PRKCE (By
CC       similarity). Interacts with SSH1 and TORC2/CRTC2. Interacts ..
```

When i finish with the block "function", my parser will always jump one line at the end and escapes therefore the line with "SUBUNIT" that i can't get anymore :(

Here is an example of a file I need to parse:

```
    CC   -!- FUNCTION: Adapter protein implicated in the regulation of a large
    CC       spectrum of both general and specialized signaling pathways. Binds...
    CC   -!- SUBUNIT: Homodimer. Interacts with SAMSN1 and PRKCE (By
    CC       similarity). Interacts with SSH1 and TORC2/CRTC2. Interacts with ...
    CC   -!- SUBUNIT: Homodimer. Interacts with SAMSN1 and PRKCE salut(By
    CC       similarity). Interacts with SSH1 and TORC2/CRTC2. salutInteracts with
    CC   -!- INTERACTION:
    CC       Q76353:- (xeno); NbExp=3; IntAct=EBI-359815, EBI-6248077;
    CC       Q9P0K1-3:ADAM22; NbExp=2; IntAct=EBI-359815, EBI-1567267; ...
    CC   -!- SUBCELLULAR LOCATION: Cytoplasm. Melanosome. Note=Identified by
    CC       mass spectrometry in melanosome fractions from stage I to stage
    CC       IV. ....
```

Here's a part of what I wrote. I'm trying to mark the current position in the file while reading it but the parsing doesn't work well when i do that. What am I missing here?

Cheers for any help, it would be much appreciated :)

```
            // Function
        if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- FUNCTION")) {
            String data[] = line.split("CC   -!- FUNCTION:");
            function = function + data[1];
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null && ( (line.startsWith("CC       ")) || (line.startsWith("CC   -!- FUNCTION")) ) ) {
                if (line.startsWith("CC       ")) {
                    String dataOther[] = line.split("CC      ");
                    function = function + dataOther[1];
                    prot.setFunction(function);
                    bReader.mark(size);

                }

                else if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- FUNCTION")) {
                    String dataOther[] = line.split("CC   -!- FUNCTION:");
                    function = function + "-!-"+ dataOther[1];
                    prot.setFunction(function);
                    bReader.mark(size);

                }
            }



            bReader.reset();
        }   


        // Subunit
        if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- SUBUNIT")) {
            String data[] = line.split("CC   -!- SUBUNIT:");
            subunit = subunit  + "-|-"+ data[1];
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null && ( (line.startsWith("CC       "))  ) ) {
                if (line.startsWith("CC       ")) {
                    String dataOther[] = line.split("CC      ");
                    subunit  = subunit  + dataOther[1];
                    prot.setSubunit(subunit);


                }


            }

            //bReader.reset();
        }
```

Comment: All I see is `if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- FUNCTION")) {` where is the `else if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- SUBUNIT"))`

Comment: I've just edited my question with the subunit part.

Comment: you have bReader.reset() in your first if statement, are you sure you want that there?

Comment: What I was trying to do, is to mark each line of my text block, then when i finish the loop I reset the position to the last line that has been marked so I don't have this one extra line that is escaped everytime but this is not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

.mark() and .reset() are used for more advanced techniques of reading from a buffer. I think in your case you just need to freshen up on reading data from a file. I see in your code you have multiple bReader.readLine(); that will read a line from the buffer and discard it each time, so generally you only want to .readLine once, then process it.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- FUNCTION")) {
      String line2 = br.readLine();
      //do some stuff
   }
   if (line.startsWith("CC   -!- SUBUNIT")) {
      String line2 = br.readLine();
      //do some stuff
   }
}
br.close();
```

am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The issue comes when i need to get all the block of lines corresponding to function then to subunit, I still need to do a br.readline inside each "if block" to see if the lines start with CC (see my while loop). Here is my problem, when i try to get the block of lines for function, when my parser comes to the last line of the function block, it still jumps one extra line, and that's my problem because i can't get then the subunit line, since it's escaped from the previous loop in function. Sorry if i'm not explaining well.

Comment: I do not know if every time you have FUNCTION and SUBUNIT if 1 line will always exist under it or not, if that is the case then the edits I made reflect a 2nd br.readLine(); to grab the next line under FUNCTION or SUBUNIT

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I forgot to say, the number of lines for the block function, subunit and others are not fixed. They can be from 1 to several lines. So i can't jump only one line. That's why i have added a while loop.

Comment: and there can be several functions and subunits. The function i wrote above works for all those cases, but i just would like before closing the loop to reset the position to the last line of the function block for instance. Is there an easy way to do this pleasE?

Comment: sorry I must get back to work friend but just understand br.readLine(); reads the line from the buffer and discards it, there is no going back

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggestion. Yes that's why i was hoping to use the mark and reset function, but i'll have to read more about it. Cheers.